# How do I modify the response body on an Authorization Failure (403)?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I want to modify the response body of Authorization Failures (403 Forbidden).
I currently get a 403 error, however I can't find the right spot to intercept the middleware / filters to modify the response body.

I'm using an `AuthorizeAttribute` on my route like so

```
[Authorize(Roles = Constants.Roles.MyRole)]
public IActionResult GetResources() { /* ... */ }
```

and set up the Authentication.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => 
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<TokenValidationParameters>();
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents(){
            OnChallenge = context => { /* handle authentication errors (401) */ }
            OnAuthenticationFailed  = context => { /* This never seems to get hit */ }
            OnMessageRecieved = context => { /* always hit but authorization not hit yet */ }
            OnTokenValidated = context => { /* always hit but authorization not hit yet */ }
        };
    });
```

I've tried adding a requirement to my AuthorizeFilter and adding an ExceptionFilter.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddRequirements(new ReturnErrorRequirement())
        .Build()));
    options.Filters.Add(new MyExceptionFilter());
});
```

However my ReturnErrorHandler gets called before the [AuthorizeAttribute]'s handler and the exception filter does not get hit at all.

In desperation I've created my own custom attribute and authorization handler for roles.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class AllowedRoleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public AllowedRoleAttribute(string role)
    {
        Role = role;
    }

    public string Role
    {
        get;
    }
}


public class RouteAccessHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RouteAccessRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RouteAccessRequirement requirement)
    {
        //get roles from claims
        var roles = context.User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();

        //get allowed roles from route method
        var authorizationFilterContext = (AuthorizationFilterContext) context.Resource;
        var descriptor = (ControllerActionDescriptor) authorizationFilterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        var allowedRoles = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(descriptor.MethodInfo, typeof(AllowedRoleAttribute)).Cast<AllowedRoleAttribute>().ToList();

        //determine if we have a match
        if (!allowedRoles.Any() || roles.Any(role =>
            allowedRoles.Any(allowedRole =>
                role.Value == allowedRole.Role)))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else 
        {
            // Modify response
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

However this feels like a hack.

The [documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/controllers/filters/sample) doesn't have any examples of this and my google-fu is failing me.

How do I modify the response body on an Authorization Failure?